# If measure of a every set is $0$ then measure of the union of those sets is $0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to prove the following property:

If $\mu(E_j) = 0$ for all $j \geq 1$, then $\mu(\cup_{j\geq1} E_j) = 0$.

In order to prove this can I just state that if $E_j$ has measure $0$ then it follows that it must be the empty set $\emptyset$ and therefore the union of empty sets is the empty set itself so it follows that $\mu(\cup_{j\geq1} E_j)  = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

Please tell me if my reasoning is correct and if not please tell what I need to do in order to prove this propertie.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of measure zero is generally not the empty set. For example, the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the non-empty set $\{1\}$ is zero.

Actually, here we can use the sub-additivity of measure.
$$\mu\left(\cup_j E_j\right)\leq \sum_j\mu(E_j)=0$$
so $\mu\left(\cup_j E_j\right)=0$.